# Java, JavaScript: Avoid escaping particular HTML tags

Tags: java, javascript

I am using `org.apache.commons.lang.StringEscapeUtils` to escape HTML tags:

```
StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml(str);
```

What I want is to avoid escaping few particular tags. e.g.

```
<h1>this is h1</h1>
<ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>
```

After escaping it should connvert all `<` to `&lt;` and `>` to `&gt;` except `<ul>` and `<li>` tag. Here i don't want to escape `<ul>` `<li>` tags because in HTML page i have to show content as list so i need ul and li.

How can i do this in java and javascript.

Answer (score 1):

You don't want a simple string escape util, which is what you're using.

What you want is an HTML sanitizer, like the [OWASP Java HTML Sanitizer](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Java_HTML_Sanitizer_Project). It allows whitelists of HTML tags to not escape, e.g., [custom HTML policies](http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/javadoc/org/owasp/html/HtmlPolicyBuilder.html) with which you can specify allowed tags, in case the [default sanitizers](http://owasp-java-html-sanitizer.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/distrib/javadoc/org/owasp/html/Sanitizers.html) don't meet your needs.

Other libraries also do this, like [JSoup](http://jsoup.org/) with its [cleaning functionality](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/cleaning-html/whitelist-sanitizer).

Comment: which one is preferable

Comment: @Manish Preference questions are OT for SO. Whichever suits your needs best.

Comment: its good but the problem is its removes tag e.g <h1> completly. that i dont want what i want is just encode it